# Second Level of Settings in WordPress Dashboard Jump to Apache Default Page

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, wordpress

I have an Ubuntu box with WordPress installed. I am able to login to the dashboard admin page, however, if I click further of the settings, it will jump to the Apache default page.

That's pretty weird, I can open the home page, so it shouldn't be the problem of site-enabled file.

[image]

Comment: try to configure domain with different document root  instead using default /var/www/html path. And copy your data to new one.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a little tricky. I just copied all the content of wordpress to `/var/www/html`, so it leaves the `index.html` file and this is the default site but the wordpress doesn't use it.

Simply remove this file solves the problem.